# Calling Windows 10 bash from a c program

Tags: c, bash, windows-10

I am trying to write a simple program that would parse some string and pass it to bash on Windows 10 (with the not-so-new Linux subsystem). So I try

```
system("bash");
```

(in the actual program I include some arguments for bash, but it behaves the same with or without them)

I get this error when the program launches:

```
'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I found this error is often caused by unset path variable, but it seems to be fine when I checked and I can launch bash from the command line without problem. I am using Visual Studio Express for desktop.

Update: calling `dir C:\Windows\System32` from cmd gives 4142 results, while running `system("dir C:\\Windows\\System32");` code in c gives 2839. Apparently it is not just bash the program can't see. Why is it so? Why does it not see these files?

Comment: make sure that 'bash' is available in the windows cmd shell first.

Comment: @chenchuk op already mentioned that he can launch bash from the command line without problem.

Comment: @kobo: have you tried (or can you try) with the full Windows path "C:\..." to bash.exe instead of only "bash"? Alternatively, can you check or set the %PATH% variable in a CMD shell and then start the C program binary from the same CMD shell?

Comment: @Olli tried full path, same error (except the path is also listed in the error). Tried "echo %PATH%" in cmd and it did list the bash location (C:\Windows\System32), launching the program from there brought no luck. Also tried to replace bash with notepad just to try, and THAT did open.

Comment: @kobo: I guess, you have tried both, "bash" and "bash.exe"? And both "notepad" and "notepad.exe" work fine?

Comment: When you used the full path, did you escape the backslashes?  For example:  `"C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe"`.

Comment: @Olli Notepad works with or without full path and with or without extension, bash does not work with neither, either, nor both.

Comment: @cdarke Yes, I did escape them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem - file system redirector had been causing the trouble. Using the `C:\Windows\Sysnative\bash` path works.
Thanks to all that tried to help.